# Power apps get dropdown value depending on current user

Tags: powerapps-canvas

I want to create a canvas app allowing me to set a dropdown according to the current user.

I will have a list of authorised users, and each will have specific values to access.

If Jim then A to E, if Val then F to M ... if Boss then A to Z

is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible. It can be achieved with lot of different ways.

save your mapping data user jim--> choices in SP list or dataverse table or so on and then access it.

Then based on your retrieve set the dropdown value.

Please mark it as solved if this helps.

Comment: did you managed to solve this?